# can speech recognizer take input from incoming call voice (Speaker)?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

1. During a phone call application listens to the incoming phone call
   i.e incoming voice from speaker not the mic.
2. Converts the caller's(the person who has make a call to you) voice
   to text.
3. Finally display that converted text into the text view.
4. It does all this conversion while the phone call is happening.

Comment: I think it can be possable, with googles offline speech recognition and but i just don't no how to give incoming call input directly to speech recognition.