# Android, can speech recognizer work during a call?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

While on a call, does speechRecognizer works?

Has anyone tried it?

My goal is to listen to user's voice and not the incoming voice. While researching I found this link:

[can speech recognizer take input from incoming call voice (Speaker)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521023/can-speech-recognizer-take-input-from-incoming-call-voice-speaker)

which is looking for using SpeechRecognizer for incoming voice 'during a call'.

And am looking for using SpeechRecognizer **while on the call**, just for my user's voice.

Comment: I am on very early stage of my research, thus have very little knowledge of android. Please do not downvote or atleast put a comment with whats wrong, so I correct it.

Comment: I would suggest you to try it out ;) [here](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/) you find a tutorial with sample code. Testing it should be part of the research don't you think?

Comment: I understand, but I have to start learning android from the very beginning which will take another few days of mine. This particular research is very important. Answer in yes or no will tell me to 'go' OR 'no go' with this project. I am not asking for code, I am just asking in YES or NO if someone has did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The *Internet* says **YES**!

One answer I found in a comment from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964359/how-to-convert-speech-to-text-during-call-with-different-text-colors-for-caller) question was to use [this](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-android-sdk) SDK.